# Issues with 'View as' in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, interface-builder, calayer

I'm currently having issues when I try to use the 'View as' option in interface builder.

When select 'View as' for, for example, iPhone 8 Plus, all the views constraints update so that it looks fine on iPhone 8 Plus in interface builder, but subviews of UITableViewCells do not update in interface builder. This can be seen in the screenshots below.

[Viewing as iPhone 8 Plus, switched from viewing as iPhone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA60s.png)

[Viewing as iPhone X, switched from viewing as iPhone 8 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPqBr.png)

Normally this wouldn't really bother me, as it builds and all constraints are updated, but when I build the app, for some reason a CAGradientLayer I have setup on the master subview of the UITableViewCell does not update to these constraints, and keeps the constraints of the previous 'View as' option.

[CAGradientLayer constraint issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swcvo.png)

I have tried to override `layoutSublayers(of: CALayer)` and then update the width of the CALayer to update the new width of the UIView, but this does not work as the frame of the UIView is not updating to reflect the updated constraints.

Is there any way I can get the width of the UIView with the constraints applied? Or is there a fix I can apply in Xcode that would fix this.

Many thanks,

-William

Comment: where are you setting the gradient ?

Comment: @GIJOW I have an extension of UIView that is used to create and set the gradient.

Comment: Can you test... if you set the gradient on viewDidAppear for example does it works ?

Comment: @GIJOW I'm setting the gradient inside a UITableViewCell class, where the viewDidAppear function is not available. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update the frame of the gradient inside `layoutSubviews`

```
override func layoutSubviews() 
  super.layoutSubviews()
  // set the frame of the gradient here 
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, I updated the layers width to match it's superview width, like so: `layer.frame.size.width = bgView.frame.size.width`.

Comment: Does **bgView** take it's width right ??, can you share this cell custom class  code  and image of IB/xib